# Windows can't view secondary Ubuntu hard drive files

Tags: windows, filesystem

Currently I have two hard drives on my laptop one has Windows 8.1 on it and the second one has Ubuntu 14.04. The problem is when I boot into Ubuntu I can view and modify files on my Windows hard drive, but when I'm booted in Windows I can't view the files on my Ubuntu hard drive.

The hard drive shows up in Windows disk management but none of the drives/volumes have assigned letters on the Ubuntu hard drive, and I can't even assign a letter to the hard drive using diskpart command line.

Is it even possible for Windows to access the files on my Ubuntu hard drive, which is NTFS formatted by the way, or do I just not have something set up right to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless your Ubuntu hard drive have a NTFS file system you cannot view/edit the files on that hard drive in Windows. Linux however have support for a vast range of file systems allowing you to edit your window drive.

If you want to access your Ubuntu drive you can check out [this](http://www.howtogeek.com/112888/3-ways-to-access-your-linux-partitions-from-windows/) link which show 3 ways of accessing your Ubuntu file system. The article may be irrelevant if you do not use the ext4 filesystem.

Comment: Thanks for the link and the help. I thought my Ubuntu drive was formatted in NTFS but apparently it was ext3.

Comment: either ntfs or fat based filesystems are supported by windows outside of some partition editors